# undefined referance to function included in header

Tags: c, compilation, header

I would apreciate any insights to a couple of linker and compiler issues I have

I have main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "assemble.h"

char *fileName;
FILE *file;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char inputFile[MAX_INPUT];
int i, flag = TRUE;

for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
    fileName = argv[i];
    strcpy(inputFile,argv[i]);
    file = fopen(inputFile,"r");
    }
        flag = assemble(file, fileName); //****this is the problam line****
        if(!flag)
            printf("Errors found, compilation aborted\n");
        else
            printf("File %s compiled\n", fileName);
        fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```

In the header assemble.h I have the decleration:

```
int assemble(FILE *file, char *fileName);
```

The first issue is in main.c I get undefined referance to 'assemble', id returned 1 exit status

The second issue is in assemble.h I get FILE was not declared in this scope.

Does anyone know what causes these errors and what is the fix?
Thanks in advance

[EDIT]: the makefile.

```
assembler: main.o assemble.o functions.o 
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.o assemble.o functions.o -o assembler -lm

main.o: main.c assemble.c
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c main.c assemble.c -lm

assemble.o: assemble.c
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c assemble.c -lm

functions.o: functions.c
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c functions.c -lm

clean:
    rm -f assembler
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: where is this `assemble.h` is coming from? It has to have some `*.c` file along..

Comment: `assemble.h` file should be in the same directory your `main.c` is in.

Comment: `id returned 1` should be `ld returned 1`. `ld` is short for `load`, it's the name of the linker on Unix.

Comment: The `return 0;` line is outside the `main()` function. You have an extra `}` before that line.

Comment: assemble.h is the header of assemble.c file where the assemble function is defined all files are in the same directory.

Comment: Are you compiling it together with `main`?? OK, let's make it simple. *How* are you compiling it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error about `FILE was not declared`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.
assembler: main.o assemble.o functions.o 
 gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.o assemble.o functions.o -o assembler -lm

main.o: main.c assemble.c
 gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c main.c assemble.c -lm

assemble.o: assemble.c
 gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c assemble.c -lm

functions.o: functions.c
 gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c functions.c -lm

clean:
 rm -f assembler
 rm -f *.o

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>` in `assemble.c`? Because plainly, when you compile `main.c` you have already included it so you can't get an error about `FILE` from `assemble.h` here.

Comment: Include this makefile in the question body

Comment: Perhaps you have more stray `}` closures like the one you deleted from the `main` in the post. They can cause strange compiler errors.

Comment: The line in makefile `main.o: main.c assemble.c` doesn't seem to make sense.. Remove the `assemble.c` from there.

Comment: just an aside, there's no need for the `-lm` flag for the `main.o:`, `assemble.o:`, and `functions.o:` targets in your makefile. Those are just compiling, you're not actually linking until the `assembler:` target.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile both files and link them together.

```
gcc main.c assemble.c
```

Or compile them separately to object files and link them.

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c assemble.c
gcc main.o assemble.o
```